# Hibernate mapping exception with multiple @Id

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I have two entities with a relation between them.
Here's my first entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "APPLICATION_DEVICE")
    public class ApplicationDevice implements Serializable {
    [...]
    @Id
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "udid", nullable=false)
        public Device getDevice()
        {
            return device;
        }

        public void setDevice(Device device)
        {
            this.device = device;
        }

        @Id
        public Long getApplicationId()
        {
            return applicationId;
        }

        public void setApplicationId(Long applicationId)
        {
            this.applicationId = applicationId;
        }
[...]
```

Note it has a primery key with two fields: applicationId and a device (it is as another relation).

And my other entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SEGMENT_APPLICATION_DEVICES")
public class SegmentApplicationDevice
{
[...]

@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public ApplicationDevice getApplicationDevice()
    {
        return applicationDevice;
    }

    public void setApplicationDevice(ApplicationDevice applicationDevice)
    {
        this.applicationDevice = applicationDevice;
    }

[...]
```

And here's the exception of hibernate when it tries mapping this entities:

```
Exception constructing service 'HibernateSessionSource': Error invoking service builder method org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.HibernateCoreModule.buildHibernateSessionSource(Logger, List, RegistryShutdownHub) (at HibernateCoreModule.java:123) (for service 'HibernateSessionSource'): Foreign key (FK5B8CB9821C11FEAE:SEGMENT_APPLICATION_DEVICES [applicationDevice_applicationId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (APPLICATION_DEVICE [udid,applicationId])
```

What i'm doint wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ApplicationDevice has a composite id consisting of 2 columns. the manytoone to ApplicationDevice however doesn't specify columns (there should be 2) so the default of one column with "entityname_id" is used.

To mitigate this do specify the **two** columns at the manytoone which are the joincolumns to ApplicationDevice.